# Graph density with scatterplot ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, scatter-plot, density-plot

i Have the following dataset :

```
Amount  Age

201,1  17
292,2  19
218,2  12
292,1  19
```

And I want to plot the density of the age and then add the mean amount by age with scatter plot

[image: A bit like that]

where frequency mean is the graph ("fréquence moyenne") is the mean amount

Thank you

Comment: what have you tried so far to solve your question?

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)

df1 <- data.frame(Amount= c(201.1, 292.2, 218.2, 292.1), Age=c(17,19,12,19))
df2 <- df1 %>% group_by(Age) %>% summarise(Amount=mean(Amount))
df2$amount2 <- df2$Amount /200

ggplot(data=df1, aes(x=Age)) +geom_density()+
  geom_point(data=df2, aes(x=Age, y=amount2))
```

Note that, as the scales of the means and the densities vary across orders of magnitude, I had to rescale the mean amounts.